Solr 9.6 works only on docker
After I installed solr on my machine to test for upgrade implementation to the latest 9.6.1 version I get no error in starting up solr, however when I access localhost:8983 or localhost:8983/solr/#/ I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
The logs look like this:
starting logs:
./solr start

*** [WARN] *** Your open file limit is currently 1024.  
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
*** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 55511.
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [|]  
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=7807). Happy searching!

this is the solr.log:
2024-07-23 14:02:14.374 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.e.j.s.Server jetty-10.0.20; built: 2024-01-29T20:46:45.278Z; git: 3a745c71c23682146f262b99f4ddc4c1bc41630c; jvm 11.0.23+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04.1
2024-07-23 14:02:17.943 WARN  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.e.j.u.DeprecationWarning Using @Deprecated Class org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner
2024-07-23 14:02:18.028 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider Using logger factory org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory
2024-07-23 14:02:18.047 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider  ___      _       Welcome to Apache Solr™ version 9.6.1
2024-07-23 14:02:18.047 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider / __| ___| |_ _   Starting in standalone mode on port 8983
2024-07-23 14:02:18.047 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider \__ \/ _ \ | '_|  Install dir: /mnt/c/users/cosmin/Downloads/solr-9.6.1
2024-07-23 14:02:18.047 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider |___/\___/_|_|    Start time: 2024-07-23T14:02:18.047773Z
2024-07-23 14:02:18.051 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider Solr started with "-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError" that will crash on any OutOfMemoryError exception. The cause of the OOME will be logged in the crash file at the following path: /mnt/c/users/cosmin/Downloads/solr-9.6.1/server/logs/jvm_crash_7807.log
2024-07-23 14:02:18.121 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider Solr Home: /mnt/c/users/cosmin/Downloads/solr-9.6.1/server/solr (source: system property: solr.solr.home)
2024-07-23 14:02:18.168 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.c.SolrXmlConfig Loading solr.xml from /mnt/c/users/cosmin/Downloads/solr-9.6.1/server/solr/solr.xml
2024-07-23 14:02:18.269 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader Added 1 libs to classloader, from paths: [/mnt/c/users/cosmin/Downloads/solr-9.6.1/lib]
2024-07-23 14:02:20.368 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.u.t.SimplePropagator Always-on trace id generation enabled.
2024-07-23 14:02:21.010 WARN  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.u.StartupLoggingUtils Jetty request logging enabled. Will retain logs for last 3 days. See chapter "Configuring Logging" in reference guide for how to configure.
2024-07-23 14:02:21.020 WARN  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Not all security plugins configured!  authentication=disabled authorization=disabled.  Solr is only as secure as you make it. Consider configuring authentication/authorization before exposing Solr to users internal or external.  See https://s.apache.org/solrsecurity for more info
2024-07-23 14:02:21.541 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.c.CorePropertiesLocator Found 0 core definitions underneath /mnt/c/users/cosmin/Downloads/solr-9.6.1/server/solr
2024-07-23 14:02:22.219 WARN  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.g.j.m.i.MessagingBinders A class jakarta.activation.DataSource for a default provider MessageBodyWriter<jakarta.activation.DataSource> was not found. The provider is not available.
2024-07-23 14:02:22.950 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.j.SolrRequestAuthorizer Creating a new SolrRequestAuthorizer
2024-07-23 14:02:23.242 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6c451c9c{solr-jetty-context.xml,/solr,file:///mnt/c/users/cosmin/Downloads/solr-9.6.1/server/solr-webapp/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/mnt/c/users/cosmin/Downloads/solr-9.6.1/server/solr-webapp/webapp}
2024-07-23 14:02:23.259 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.e.j.s.RequestLogWriter Opened /mnt/c/users/cosmin/Downloads/solr-9.6.1/server/logs/2024_07_23.request.log
2024-07-23 14:02:23.266 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.e.j.s.AbstractConnector Started ServerConnector@878452d{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1, h2c)}{127.0.0.1:8983}
2024-07-23 14:02:23.270 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.e.j.s.Server Started Server@6326d182{STARTING}[10.0.20,sto=0] @11571ms

about the CrashOnOutOfMemoryError warning i have no crash report
and i get roughly the same from solr-8983-console.log
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory. (error = 1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory. (error = 12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory. (error = 12)
2024-07-23 14:02:14.374 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.e.j.s.Server jetty-10.0.20; built: 2024-01-29T20:46:45.278Z; git: 3a745c71c23682146f262b99f4ddc4c1bc41630c; jvm 11.0.23+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04.1
2024-07-23 14:02:17.943 WARN  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.e.j.u.DeprecationWarning Using @Deprecated Class org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner
2024-07-23 14:02:18.028 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider Using logger factory org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory
2024-07-23 14:02:18.047 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider  ___      _       Welcome to Apache Solr™ version 9.6.1
2024-07-23 14:02:18.047 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider / __| ___| |_ _   Starting in standalone mode on port 8983
2024-07-23 14:02:18.047 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider \__ \/ _ \ | '_|  Install dir: /mnt/c/users/cosmin/Downloads/solr-9.6.1
2024-07-23 14:02:18.047 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider |___/\___/_|_|    Start time: 2024-07-23T14:02:18.047773Z
2024-07-23 14:02:18.051 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.s.CoreContainerProvider Solr started with "-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError" that will crash on any OutOfMemoryError exception. The cause of the OOME will be logged in the crash file at the following path: /mnt/c/users/cosmin/Downloads/solr-9.6.1/server/logs/jvm_crash_7807.log

the status is running and I do not see any problem in the logs
I am using java 11 which is the recommended version
I tried reinstalling the tar file and starting solr again.
i increased the open file limit to:
ulimit -n 65000
ulimit -u 65000

I tried allocating more memory to java heap
SOLR_HEAP="512m"
and SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms512m -Xmx1g"
i checked the ports and moved solr to 8984 but still the same issue
Only when i installed solr on docker it worked but since i need to delete and remake a lot of cores i would’ve prefered running solr on local machine instead of docker.
Wsl and vms also don’t work

After you start it, what do you see if you browse to http://localhost:8983 or if you curl localhost:8983/solr/ (notice the / at the end) ?

You can also run ./solr status after it starts to check that it is indeed running

when i open localhost in browser i get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and with curl i get connection refused prolly meaning its nothing to load
i ran status and specified in my post that its running

The out memory message is an INFO message so I don't think that's the culprit. But I have no idea else is going on.
